# How can I dismissPopover from the other view?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, popover, dismiss

I have a problem like this:
I have a root view which has a UIPopoverController and a button, when I click on that button, it present a tableView. My app display OK but now when I click in any row, the UIPopoverController still display and I want it dismiss.

Any help? Thanks!

This is my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIPopoverIphone.h"
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, TableViewPopoverDelegate> {
    TableViewController *popoverView;
    IBOutlet UIButton *popButton;
    UIPopoverController *pop;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *pop;

+(void)hidePop;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize pop;

-(void)dealloc {
    [pop release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(IBAction)showPop {
    popoverView = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    popoverView.delegate = self;
    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverView];
    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 200)];
    [pop setDelegate:self];
    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:popButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}


-(void)hidePop {
    [pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

....

@end
```

**TableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TableViewPopoverDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) dismissPopover;

@end

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray;
    UITableView *tableView;
    id<TableViewPopoverDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *itemsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TableViewPopoverDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@implementation TableViewController


@synthesize itemsArray;
@synthesize tableView;


-(void) dealloc {
    [itemsArray release];
    [tableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)loadView {
    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200)];
    self.view = mainView;
    [mainView release];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate   = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

....

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    [self.delegate dismissPopover];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current work flow, the `ViewController` have no connection with `TableViewController`.  It looks like you are presenting the `UITableViewController` from the `UIPopoverIphone` not from the `ViewController`.  So the delegate callback method `dismissPopover` needed to be implemented within the `UIPopoverIphone` class not the `ViewController` class.  If you still want to dismiss the `UIPopoverIphone` from the `ViewController`, there are two options:

1. Using `NSNotificationCenter`:  In the `TableViewController`, you can post a notification when you are ready to dismiss the popover.  Then in the `ViewController`, you can observer that notification and dismiss the popover.  In this scenario, no delegate is involved.
2. Setup the delegate callback from your `UIPopoverIphone` class and the `ViewController` class.  So when you tap the button in the popover, it makes a callback to `ViewController`, you then dismiss the popover and prepare your `TableViewController` and present it.  Here your `TableViewController` and the `ViewController` have a connection.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your root view `ViewController` doesn't correctly implement your `TableViewPopoverDelegate`. You've declared a method in that delegate called `dismissPopover`, but you haven't implemented it in ViewController.m.

In ViewController.m, change the hidePop function to:

```
-(void)dismissPopover {
    [pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Popovers by default dismiss themselves when a tap is detected outside of their bounds.

Comment: OK, I know, but I want dismiss by selecting row of tableView which it present